# Change Response status code using @ControllerAdvice and @ResponseStatus

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am using spring mvc, to handle excpetion i use global exception handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT, reason = "Data integrity violation")
    @ExceptionHandler({DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
    public @ResponseBody AdminResponse handleConflict(DataIntegrityViolationException ex,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

        AdminResponse error = new AdminResponse ();

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());
        error.setStatus(Status.FAILURE);
        error.setErrorDescription(ex.getMessage());

        return error;
    }
```

as i know, the annotation  `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT` will change the repose status code into `HttpStatus.CONFLICT`, but that is not happen.
when i created dummy exception and annotated this dummy exception with `@ResponseStatus` then throw this new exception, the `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` catches and handle the exception and also changes the response status code.

how can i change the response status code without creating new Exception, i just need to catch `DataIntegrityViolationException`

Comment: I don't quite get it: does it change response status or not? if so - what's the problem?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich, no it doesn't change response status.

Answer (score 1):

You take to two way.

**1. use @ResponseBody and return custom JSON String.**

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpClientErrorException.class, HTTPException.class })
public @ResponseBody String checkHTTPException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception,
        HttpServletResponse resp) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CommonExceptionModel model = new CommonExceptionModel();

    model.setMessage("400 Bad Request");
    model.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());

    String commonExceptionString = mapper.writeValueAsString(model);

    return commonExceptionString;
}
```

**2. use ResponseEntity and exception**

Return ResponseEntity.

```
ResponseEntity.status(exception.getStatusCode()).headers(exception.getResponseHeaders())
                            .body(exception.getResponseBodyAsString());
```